# Overwrite a File in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to write into a text file in node.js.
Im doing this the following way:

```
fs.writeFile("persistence\\announce.txt", string, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log("Error writing file: " + err);
    }
});
```

whereas string is a variable.

This function will begin it`s writing always at the beginning of a file, so it will overwrite previous content.

I have a problem in the following case:

old content:

```
Hello Stackoverflow
```

new write:

```
Hi Stackoverflow
```

Now the following content will be in the file:

```
Hi stackoverflowlow
```

The new write was shorter then the previous content, so part of the old content is still persistent.

**My question:**

What do I need to do, so that the old content of a file will be completely removed before the new write is made?

Comment: take a look at the official documentation, you will find something for sure, writeStream or somehting like that or some kind of option. https://nodejs.org/api/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try truncating the file first:

```
fs.truncate("persistence\\announce.txt", 0, function() {
    fs.writeFile("persistence\\announce.txt", string, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log("Error writing file: " + err);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename the old file and append to therefore a non existent file (creating a new one). This way you have on the one hand a backup and on other hand a fresh updated file `./config.json`:

```
fs.renameSync('./config.json', './config.json.bak')
fs.appendFileSync('./config.json', text)
```

(sync version, might throw)