# What's the best way to overwrite a file using fs in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to overwrite an existing file.
I'm first checking if the file exists using:

```
fs.existsSync(path)
```

If file does not exit I'm creating and writing using:

```
fs.writeFileSync(path,string)
```

The problem is when the file already exists and I want to over write all its contents.
Is there a single line solution, so far I searched and found solutions that use 
fs.truncate & fs.write, but is there a one hit solution?

Comment: Doesn't writeFileSync overwrite the file by default?

Comment: try this `fs.writeFileSync(path, string, { flag: fs.constants.O_TRUNC | fs.constants.O_WRONLY })`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Found the solution.
fs.writeFileSync gets a third arguments for options that can be an object.
So if you get the "File already exist" you should do.

```
fs.writeFileSync(path,content,{encoding:'utf8',flag:'w'})
```

Comment: from what I see in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) that flag is the default..perhaps you were using it with a different flag

Comment: What is mentioned in the doc is not actually working, I have to explicitly define the W mode.

Answer (score 170):

`fs.writeFileSync` and `fs.writeFile` overwrite the file by default, there is no need for extra checks if this is what you want to do. This is mentioned in the docs:

[fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

> Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists.

Comment: I got an Error of "File already exist" when the file was already existing.
That was the main part of the question, but tnx anyway.

Comment: I am having case where I edit `package.json` and it does not work for some reason. , maybe the file is lock, how can I ensure it will work ?

Answer (score 6):

When you say "best way", i think at performance and scalability and i'd say use the [asynchronous method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178903/overwrite-a-file-in-node-js)

`fs.writeFileSync(path,string)` as the name suggest is synchronous (blocking api) the thread is held for the whole lifecycle of the request, that means your nodejs thread will be blocked until the operation finishes and this behavior in a production environment with simultaneous connections from multiple clients could kill your app.

Do not think at the single line of code, less code doesn't mean better performance.

Comment: The main issue was that I got a "File already exist " when I used fs.writeFileSync on a file that already existed.

Comment: Of course 'THE BEST' is always contingent on the environment, situation and perspective. Asynchronous is obviously, more times than not, 'THE BEST'  way to go with javascript, however; I am building a small footprint 'NodeJS Framework' right now and when I call index.js to start my server everything is synchronous so I can use try and catch blocks, once the server is running everything ('http requestes mostly, are proceseed asynchronously for nonblocking.