# How do I overwrite a file with the fs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs

I'm making an electron app for windows. When I try to overwrite a txt file it just deletes everything. I want that but the content I am trying to put is not writing to the file.
Here is the code for when receive a prompt to save:

```
ipcRenderer.on('saveFile', function(){
        console.log(fileData.path)
        fs.writeFile(fileData.path, editor.innerText, 'utf8', (err) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('File Saved')
        })
    })
```

Here is the code when I send the file data (file path, text in file, etc.):

```
fileBtn.addEventListener('change', function(e){
        if(fileBtn.files[0].type.substring(0, 4) == 'text'){
            file.ext = fileBtn.files[0].name.substr(fileBtn.files[0].name.indexOf('.'))
            console.log(fileBtn.files[0])
            file.path = fileBtn.files[0].path
            file.text = fs.readFileSync(file.path, 'utf8');
            ipcRenderer.send('newFile', file)
        }else{
            console.error('Not a valid file type')
            return;
        }

    })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892482/whats-the-best-way-to-overwrite-a-file-using-fs-in-node-js

Comment: You are not accounting for the asynchronous behaviour, the file is not yet populated with the data when you read it.  Using writeFileSync might help, but even then you need to be sure things happen in the right order, that you read the file after writeFileSync is complete.

Comment: Wait, so I need to write to the file before I read it? Also, I am reading and writing to the txt files, in different files