# How can i store firebase data to json in local

Tags: node.js, firebase, discord.js

In my case I got the data from firestore now how can I save it to
`serversettings.json`:

```
var temp = {}
let query = db.collection('guilds')
let data = query.get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>',doc.data());          
    })
```

so I get the output as:

```
637301291068030997 => { welcomeChannelID: '<#648968505160630285>',
guildMemberCount: 4,
guildOwnerID: '348832732647784460',
guildOwner: 'Ethical Hacker',
prefix: '.',
guildID: '637301291068030997',
guildName: 'test server 3' }
```

and this:

```
GUqGqFanJuN7cRJx4S2w => {}
```

I need to save that data to `serversettings.json`

```
await fs.writeFile ("../serversettings.json", JSON.stringify(temp), function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('done');
    })
```

here temp is variable where multiple data is stored like a:{},b:{}....

i tried `var temp = {} temp.table = []` and then `temp.table.push(doc.id, ':',doc.data())`
but i get empty output so what can i do to get that expected output ?

also, adding to that how can I update the values if that object is already present in `JSON` will the above function work the same will it override the same value or delete all other values example update prefix from. to, then `await fs.writeFile ("../serversettings.json", JSON.stringify(temp),.....` so the temp field has a value of only guild id and that field prefix will it update the only prefix and not delete anything else in that array?

HERE is the code that added stuff to temp variable

```
    var temp = {}
    temp.guilds = []                                 // after some lines 
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>',doc.data());    // output is above this code
            temp.guilds.push(doc.id = doc.data())    // output is below this code
        })
```

Above codes output

```
{ guilds:
   [ { guildID: '637301291068030997', // here missing doc.id field 
       guildName: 'test server 3',
       welcomeChannelID: '-',
       guildMemberCount: 4,
       guildOwnerID: '348832732647784460',
       guildOwner: 'Ethical Hacker',
       prefix: '.' },
     {}   // this missing thing before {} is (some number) also bracket is empty by the way so no worries 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: `query.get().then(snapshot => {` is an async operation not synchronous

Comment: For second part of your question refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892482/whats-the-best-way-to-overwrite-a-file-using-fs-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

A fast solution for your issue would be to replace

```
let data = query.get().then(snapshot => {
```

with

```
await query.get().then(snapshot => {
```

so that your `temp` object can be filled before the program proceeds to save the file.

---

I haven't used `writeFile` yet, but here's what its [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) says:

> When file is a `filename`, asynchronously writes data to the file, **replacing** the file if it already exists.

I don't think your object will be so large that a complete overwrite would be a problem, unless it's changing very often. In that case, I guess you'd have to use a different method that can support an *offset*, so that you can write only what has changed, but that seems like a real overkill.

---

Regarding the format of your JSON file, I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
var temp = {};
temp.guilds = {};
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    temp.guilds[doc.id] = doc.data();
});
```

Comment: i am having issues saving it to variable since the output of temp variable is not valid json file

Comment: @ETHYT I don't understand. `JSON.stringify(temp)` does exactly that: it creates a valid json string for `temp`. Can you show where the problem is in your code?

Comment: the output expected is `11digitnumer :{new array} `but that `11digitnumber` is missing
this portion in the qustion `637301291068030997 =>` is not present in temp variable it is directly starting from  `{ welcomeChannelID:`

Comment: @ETHYT ah I see. Can you show the code that adds stuff in the `temp` variable?

Comment: check the question i added it there temp variable code

Comment: got a solution for that here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077306/how-can-i-add-these-values-to-array/60078227#60078227

Comment: @ETHYT exactly. Or you can save a line by doing `var temp = {guilds: {}};`

Answer (score 0):

i`m not sure , but firebase has method to convert data from object to JSON, so i think this solution should work

```
let query = db.collection('guilds')
let data = query.get().then(snapshot => {
        let temp = snapshot.toJSON()
        await fs.writeFile ("../serversettings.json", temp, function(err) {
           if (err) throw err;
           console.log('done');
        })
    })
```

Comment: snapshot.toJSON is not a function

Comment: Hmm, whats logg if you will try `console.log(snapshot)`

Comment: the log is very big it contains the signature and many other things also 
instead of `snapshot.toJSON()` `JSON.stringify(snapshot)` is working

Comment: So you can write it to file now