# How can i add these values to array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, discord.js

I am having trouble while adding these array

```
637301291068030997 => { guildMemberCount: 4,
guildOwnerID: '348832732647784460',
guildOwner: 'Ethical Hacker',
prefix: '.',
guildID: '637301291068030997',
guildName: 'test server 3',
welcomeChannelID: '-' },
(some number) => {other array}
```

in the above array i am receiving `637301291068030997` number in `doc.id` variable and rest is getting in `doc.data()`

my code is something like this

```
var temp = {}
temp.guilds = []                                 // after some lines 
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>',doc.data());    // output is above array shown 
        temp.guilds.push(doc.id = doc.data())    // output of this line is given below this code
    })
```

here is output of `temp.guilds.push` the missing value is `doc.id` or `637301291068030997`

```
{ guilds:
   [ { guildID: '637301291068030997',
       guildName: 'test server 3',
       welcomeChannelID: '-',
       guildMemberCount: 4,
       guildOwnerID: '348832732647784460',
       guildOwner: 'Ethical Hacker',
       prefix: '.' },
     {}   // this missing thing before {} is (some number) also bracket is empty by the way so no worries 
  ] 
}
```

what can i do so that i will get the output like below in a variable

```
  {
    "637301291068030997": [
      {
        "guildMemberCount": 4,
        "guildOwnerID": "348832732647784460",
        "guildOwner": "Ethical Hacker",
        "prefix": ".",
        "guildID": "637301291068030997",
        "guildName": "test server 3",
        "welcomeChannelID": "-"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Issue in saving to the temp to the file  file

```
await fs.writeFileSync ("./data/json/serversettings.json", JSON.stringify(temp), function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('done');
        })
```

saving this much

```
{"guilds":[]}
```

not saving anything inside it but `console.log(temp)` is giving correct output

Comment: Why do you want (in your desired result) `"637301291068030997"` to have an *array* as value? Do you expect multiple entries in that array? Why not the object without the array wrapper?

Comment: I agree with @trincot. The data structure that you are going for doesn't provide you any additional benefit over the existing one. Can you explain more as to why you need it? Using the object by itself will be substantially easier later on. I have actually made my own discord bot before and can tell you this first-hand.

Comment: yes see the output as this file will be use constantly so it will be easier if each server is in different servers id so it will be much faster

Comment: Can you please specify in your question what `snapshot` is? Are you using firebase or some other API that gives you such objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `doc.id = doc.data()` you are *assigning* the data to the `id` property. That cannot be what you want.

I would suggest to not create an array at all, but a plain (nested) object.

Like this:

```
// ...
temp.guilds = {} // plain object, not array
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    temp.guilds[doc.id] = doc.data();
})
```

If the `snapshot.forEach` implementation makes the call backs asynchronously, then make sure to wait until all call backs have been made before relying on the contents of `temp.guilds`. Promises can ease that task.

```
// ...
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    let guilds = {} // plain object, not array
    let remaining = snapshot.size; // If firebase, there is this property
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        guilds[doc.id] = doc.data();
        remaining--;
        if (!remaining) resolve(guilds);
    });
});
promise.then(function (guilds) {
    // do anything you like with guilds inside this function...
    let temp = { guilds };
    // ...
});
```

Comment: having issue saving to json file my code is updated in above qus

Comment: If your `guilds` array seems empty, you are accessing it too fast. I don't know what `snapshot` is (you didn't tell), but I guess its `forEach` method calls the callback asynchronously, so you need to await that all callbacks have been made before doing the next thing.

Comment: See addition to answer... I will assume you are using a firebase snapshot(?)