# Saving roles to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, discord

```
if (command === "roles") {
     const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
     const user = message.guild.members.cache.get(taggedUser.id)
     let rolelist = user.roles.cache
       .map(r => r.toString().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''))
     message.channel.send(rolelist);
     let rhPath = '\datastuff.json'
     let rhRead = fs.readFileSync(rhPath);
     let rhFile = JSON.parse(rhRead);
     let userId = taggedUser
     if (!rhFile[userId]) {
       rhFile[userId] = { historyRole: rolelist };
       fs.writeFileSync(rhPath, JSON.stringify(rhFile, null, 2));
     } else {
       rhFile[userId] = { historyRole: rolelist };
       fs.writeFileSync(rhPath, JSON.stringify(rhFile, null, 2));
     }
   }
```

I have this command which saves the mentioned users role id's in a JSON file. The problem is that if you are in two servers and run the command, the bot will only make one list of roles. So i assume you need to make it save the roles "per server"? How do i do that?

Comment: `writeFileSync` overwrite your file every time it is called therefore the last server that write to the file overwrite the previous one, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892482/whats-the-best-way-to-overwrite-a-file-using-fs-in-node-js

Comment: that is the way it currently is, i want to be able to save a users roles from multiple servers